Is it possible to create dynamic ASP.NET Core Razor view and controller file during runtime?
My requirement is to create dynamic razor view and controller save at project location at run time. If I call newly created controller then it will render newly created view also. The files are present at project location not virtual.
Is it possible to create dynamic Asp.net core Razor view file with controller file during runtime? If it is directly not possible, then have template in text file and possible to create .cshtml and .cshtml.cs files and render at run time?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Both official document and template can do with compilation razor pages, but the security issue needs to be considered. As to newly create controller and view, it is not supported in my research
